# How to write in next line using timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp, file-handling

I am currently working on a project which  recognizes face and then append the person's name (here name tag ) in a txt file ,named as pattern of "YYYY-MM-DD_attendance.txt" .Everything works fine but all I want to do is to append the name of the person in next line.
`/n` doesn't seems to work here .

code :

```
def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%Y-%m-%d_{fname}'): 
      return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)

with open(timeStamped('attendence.txt'),'a+') as outf:
        outf.write(name_id + "\n")
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add your code as text in a text block, not as an image.

Comment: Is "name_id" defined somewhere else in the code? Also, can you tell us exactly what error you are getting?

Comment: @C.Lewis yes name id is the name of the person recognised . I am working on facial recognition so name tag is the output name of the person infront of camera .

Comment: Understood. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @C.Lewis I am not getting any errors , all I want is to write/append the name  of the recognised person in new line every time i run the code and it recognises the person

Comment: outf: outf.write(name_id + "\n") appends  the string stored in name_id to the txt file in a single line evertime . I just want to go to a new line once this code runs ,which isn't happening

Comment: You want the name to be written and then have a blank line? or move to the next line and then write the name?

Comment: i want it to just move to the next line after writing the name

Comment: Okay, I understand. Unfortunately, your code currently does that when I run it in my python 3.7 environment. Can you post the attendance output file?

Comment: Perhaps it is an issue with the "name_id" variable, could you post an example of what that would be set to?

Comment: The txt file has my name written multiple times in a single line  . Just like          ayush!      ayush!      ayush!      ayush!      ayush!      ayush!      ayush!      ayush!

Comment: infact i changed the variable name_id and replaced it with "ayush!"....and nothing changed

Comment: Hmm, well sorry, I can't help anymore. When I run it with ```outf.write("ayush!" + "\n")``` it puts it on a new line each time I run it

Comment: @C.Lewis ok .thanks for your time.

Comment: You can try replacing `outf.write(name_id + "\n")` by `print(name_id, file=outf)`.

Comment: The problem got resolved by updating python to 3.6 ,previously it was 2.7 . I guess this issue is just for python 2. versions